# Swift KingFisher in UITableViewCell image From Url not dynamical

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, kingfisher

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = chatableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SendMsgCell", for: indexPath) as! SendMsgTableViewCell
    let msg = chatList[indexPath.row]
    if msg.emoURL != nil{
                cell.sticonFrame.kf.setImage(with: getEmojiFromURL(msg.emoURL!),completionHandler:{
                    (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
                    if image != nil{
                        cell.sticonFrame.alpha = 1
                    }else{
                        cell.sticonFrame.alpha = 0
                        cell.sticonFrame.image = nil
                    }
                })
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            }else{
                cell.sticonFrame.alpha = 0
                cell.sticonFrame.image = nil
        }
    return cell
}
```

`KingFisher` can't load First view

First scroll down can't see image
if want see image You have to come down after scroll up

`layoutIfNeeded` is not solved i haven't idea

Will see it dynamic after Once call image,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is some error please check your URL is not empty and maybe image size is big.

```
//go for this appoarch
class INSUtilities {
class func setImage(onImageView image:UIImageView,withImageUrl imageUrl:String?,placeHolderImage: UIImage) {

        if let imgurl = imageUrl{
            image.kf.indicatorType = IndicatorType.activity
            image.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: imgurl), placeholder: placeHolderImage, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            })
        }
        else{
            image.image = placeHolderImage
        }
    }
}

//incellclass call like this

//logoImg is the name of imageView

INSUtilities.setImage(onImageView: cell.sticonFrame, withImageUrl: logo!, placeHolderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pic_PlaceHolder"))
```